# Building web projects with one Terminal command

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, html, web

I'm looking for a way to create web projects using one Terminal command. The project contains the basic structure of a normal website (index.html, style.css, script.js, images folder .. etc).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a bash script to create your structure for you.
Very oversimplified example:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch index.html
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" > index.html
echo "<html>" >> index.html
echo "</html>" >> index.html
touch style.css
touch script.js

mkdir images
mkdir fonts
```

Comment: .. and can I add HTML content to the index.html to link the CSS and JS files?

Comment: Of course you can. I will update my answer.